# JOIN with GROUP_CONCAT only returning 1 row

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to return a result set that contains a delimited list of dynamic fields from another table. It seems to be working, but the result only returns one row even if I copy the same row multiple times.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT export_rules.*, GROUP_CONCAT( CAST( CONCAT( export_rule_fields.key, ': ', export_rule_fields.value ) AS char ) SEPARATOR '|') AS fields FROM export_rules
JOIN export_rule_fields ON export_rules.id = export_rule_fields.export_rule_id
WHERE export_rules.output_type = "email"
AND (export_rules.frequency = "daily" 
    AND export_rules.last_execution < TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
    AND (export_rules.cron_expression = "25 11 * * *" 
        OR export_rules.cron_expression = "30 11 * * *" ))
OR (export_rules.frequency = "weekly" 
    AND export_rules.last_execution < TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
    AND (export_rules.cron_expression = "25 11 * * 5"
        OR export_rules.cron_expression = "30 11 * * 5" ))
OR (export_rules.frequency = "monthly" 
    AND export_rules.last_execution < TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
    AND (export_rules.cron_expression = "25 11 15 * *"
        OR export_rules.cron_expression = "30 11 15 * *" ))
GROUP BY export_rules.id
```

It is supposed to grab a list of crons by their corresponding expression (That part works) and then spit them out with their fields, but I think the GROUP_CONCAT or the fact that the join has multiple rows for each export rule is throwing it off.

Comment: or it's the `group by` not working as you're expecting it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it by using a LEFT JOIN instead of a regular JOIN. When I had tested it prior, I didn't have the GROUP BY export_rules.id.

This issue is resolved.